# If I have a set $E_n = \{x \in E : |f(x)| < n \}$, then what is $\bigcup_{n}^\infty E_n$ and $\bigcap_{n}^\infty E_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

> If I have a set $E_n = \{x \in E : |f(x)| < n \}$, then what is $\bigcup_{n}^\infty E_n$ and $\bigcap_{n}^\infty E_n$?

I know that the definition for $\bigcup_{n}^\infty E_n$ is that $$\bigcup_{n}^\infty E_n= \{x \in E : x \in E_n \text{ for some } n \}$$ and $$\bigcap_{n}^\infty E_n=\{x \in E : x \in E_n \text{ for all } n \}.$$

For the first one if $x \in \bigcup_{n}^\infty E_n$, then doesn't this mean that $x \in E_1$ or $x \in E_2$ or $x \in E_3, \dots$? Likewise if $x \in \bigcap_{n}^\infty E_n$, then $x \in E_n$ for every $n$. So $x \in E_1$ and $x \in E_2$ and $x \in E_3, \dots$

For the latter set I convinced my self that $\bigcap_{n}^\infty E_n= \{x \in E : |f(x)| < 1 \}$ since $x$ *must* be in $E_1$ and if $x \in E_1$ then certainly $x \in E_n$ for any $n \ge 1$ so $x$ is in all of $E_n$.

But I don't know how to think about the former one. If $x \in \bigcup_{n}^\infty E_n$. This means that $x \in E_1$ or it could be in $E_{23323}$?

Comment: You have already argued, that if $x \in E_n$ then $x \in E_{n+1},E_{n+2}...$ and so on. so which elements are not in any $E_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\{x\in E\mid|f(x)|<n\}$ is simply $E$, since, for each $x$, you have $|f(x)|<n$ for *some* $n$ (and, in fact, for infinitely many $n$'s).